Properties that do not match the properties of its corresponding data source column
I've updated a database column length from nvarchar 255 to nvarchar1000, however this error shown up.
I've already updated the length to Unicode String[DT_WSTR] 1000 in Advanced Editor -> Input and Output Properties -> Both external columns and output columns, but it is still having the same error.
This error message is coming from an Excel source, I tried to create a new connection managers and recreate the database table, but it is also not helping. Any thoughts on this?
The value contained about 319 characters in the excel cell.
Below are the error message.

[Excel Source [290]] Error: The Excel Source.Outputs[Excel Source Error Output].Columns[F1] on the error output has properties that do not match the properties of its corresponding data source column.
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: "Excel Source" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA".
Progress: Validating - 83 percent complete
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: One or more component failed validation.
Error: There were errors during task validation.


Is not using Excel an option? Honestly, it's best avoided for ETL; ACE is great at making terrible decisions you can't override.

My co-worker set it up as using Excel Source with the following settings to import whatever excel that is stored in that folder, can ACE do the same thing? I can tell from the connection string that it is using ACE.

Delay Validation = False
ConnectionString = Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="source folder with dummy excel file template directory to trick the ssis";Extended Properties="EXCEL 12.0 XML;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;READONLY=TRUE";


Tell your coworker that the magistrates of Stackoverflow said:  "Not the best design".

LOL He left the company, that's why I am picking up his work...
